# Como criar um divisor entre views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Estou criando um app que usa um `ListView` para mostrar itens e queria saber o melhor modo e mais personalizado de criar divisores entre eles, também queria saber como usar outro divisor entre dois ícones, que são as opções que ficam em um `Toolbar` na parte inferior da tela.

Quero o divisor entre itens da `ListView` tipo o Whatsapp:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas também quero usar um divisor entre ícones em um `Toolbar` como na foto, logo após o "SAVE" (não estará agindo como `ActionBar`, ficará na parte inferior, peguei a imagem pois foi a melhor que encontrei):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar um `LinearLayout` para servir de divisor em qualquer situação, mas não ficou tão legal quando o `android:divider` da `ListView`, esse é o único meio possível mesmo?

Resumindo: Tem algum meio de fazer um divisor sempre que precisar como uma view independente, que possa ser totalmente personalizável? Isso facilitaria manipular o tamanho no `ListView` e também a usar entre as opções do `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `android:divider` é um drawable.
Assim sendo pode ter o aspecto que quiser.

No caso que refere, para conseguir que ele tenha margens, use um [InsetDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html):

**divider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="45dp"
    android:insetRight="45dp" >

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF0000"  />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Os atributos

```
android:insetLeft="45dp"
android:insetRight="45dp"
```

controlam a margem esquerda e margem direita.

Use assim:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>
```

o atributo

```
android:dividerHeight="2dp"
```

define a espessura do *divider*.

Para usar de forma a separa qualquer view use-o numa ImageView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Texto"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/divider"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Texto"/>
</LinearLayout>
```